# Javascript Smooth Glide?

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to move my element, El1, from (30,40) to (30,30) in 1000 milliseconds in a *smooth* animation. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not familiar to jQuery and if you don't want to use it and increase your page size by about 50kb just for some movements, I suggest you to use one of my functions:

```
function smooth(x, max){
return Math.floor((Math.sin((x/max*Math.PI)-(Math.PI/2))+1)*max/2);
}
```

and You need a code to move that element, something like this:

```
function process(LI){
    LI = LI || Config.From;
    LI++;
    Left = smooth(LI, Config.To)
    Config.Element.style.left = Left + 'px'
    if (LI < Config.To)
    setTimeout ("process("+LI+")", 10);
}

Config = {
Element: document.getElementById('El1'),
From: 0,
To: 400
};

process();
```

Comment: You can also use the "damping" method, like this: position += (destination - position) / damping

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at the jquery libraries the animate function is exactly what you are looking for, and easy to implement.

Jquery is at http://jquery.com/

and the animate function specifically is at http://api.jquery.com/animate/

your code will look something like this

```
$('El1').animate({top: "-10px"}), 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#moveme").animate({
   top: "30px"
}, 1000);
```

Make sure there's an element with id="moveme" and css `position: absolute`